# The difference between "complain" and "complaint"

Tags: word-meaning, verbs, word-difference, nouns

What is the difference between "complain" and "complaint" (and also "to complain" and "to complaint")?

Comment: to complain = verb, complaint = noun, so "to complaint" is not a thing.

Comment: Have you bothered to look up these words in a dictionary?

Comment: @JustinYoung Google disagrees with you: https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=en&tl=ru&text=to%20complaint says that "to complaint" exists

Comment: @BillJ I looked into Google Translate and was confused

Comment: Justin Young is correct. "Complain" is a verb and "complaint" is a noun.

Comment: Google Translate is not a dictionary, unfortunately, and will frequently lead you astray.

Comment: @porton: I would note that Google Translate is not the best tool for learning languages; It tries to make the "best fit" possible. Not that if you reverse the translation from English->Russian to [Russian->English]](https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=ru&tl=en&text=жаловаться), and plug in the Russian phrase that your translation produces, the English result is "to complain".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Complain" is a verb, an action that is done. Specifically, it the act of expressing dissent with the current or former state of something.

"Complaint" is a noun, an object that can act or be acted on(such as a person, a place, a thing or an idea). It means a "statement that a situation is unsatisfactory or unacceptable." The term is often used in either a medical(to describe the ailment, injury, or symptoms one is suffering from) or legal(a formal accusation against either a person or state of affairs) context.

The two words are related in meaning; compare various words in English that act both as a verb and a noun, such as "access", "answer", and "claim". [Here](https://www.enchantedlearning.com/wordlist/nounandverb.shtml) is a list of such words.